# Select and add result of multiplying two columns from table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to put together a MySQL query to select and multiply two columns from a specific table. In addition, I'd like the query to add the results of each multiplication if the value of a third column match any other rows.

The table has these columns: `id`, `client_id`, `project_id`, `rate`, and `quantity`.

So looking for `rate` multiplied by `quantity` for each row. Then add those results if every row has the same `project_id`.

Here is what I have so far:

`SELECT rate * quantity AS total_price FROM orders WHERE client_id=1 GROUP BY project_id`

It seems to be getting me close, but not quite all the way there. It seems to be returning all the computed results in one big array, without adding related ones together. To complicate things more, there are several projects with the same `client_id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `Sum` aggregate

```
SELECT project_id,
       Sum(rate * quantity) AS total_price
FROM   orders
WHERE  client_id = 1
GROUP  BY project_id
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(rate * quantity) AS total_price FROM orders WHERE client_id=1 GROUP BY project_id
```